# using autofac inside project library

Tags: c#, autofac

i'm using in a MVC project autofac.
I've another project with the core business(dll library).
In this core, i want use autofac for retrieve some interface.

Now, if i'm in the MVC application i can use

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyService>();
```

for retrieve the service.
But in the library how can I retrieve the service without pass it as property in some class declaration?

DependencyResolver is defined only in MVC project.

Is it a best practice?

Comment: Some useful reading material: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/ and http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/

Comment: @trailmax: those posts are actually over reusable libraries, such as NuGet packages. This question is about libraries (or projects) within the same solution. I think more related to this question is http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/ and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see following issues with your approach:

1. [`DepdencyResolver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver) is defined in [System.Web.Mvc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc), and your BL-project should not reference that assembly.
2. You are using the [Service Locator Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx), which is [declared an Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

**Avoid the System.Web.Mvc-dependency in your BL-project**

I found a specific `Locator<T>` is a practicable approach, which circumnavigates the *"open to everything"*- and *static*-issue of the Service Locator Pattern:

```
public interface ILocator<T> // defined in some *CORE* project
{
  T Locate();
}

public class AutofacLocator<T> : ILocator<T> // defined and injected in your *FRONTEND* project
{
  public AutofacLocator(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
  {
    this.LifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
  }

  public virtual T Locate()
  {
    var service = this.LifetimeScope.Resolve<T>();

    return service;
  }
}
```

This can simply be registered as an [open generic](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components):

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(AutofacLocator<>))
       .As(typeof(ILocator<>))
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

So, instead of depending on the static [`DependencyResolver.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver.current), you create your own resolver, and inject it in the BL-class' ctor:

```
public class SomeBusinessLogic
{
  public SomeBusinessLogic(ILocator<SomeDependency> someDependencyLocator)
  {
  }
}
```

**Use Ctor-Injection instead of the Service Locator Pattern**

Another approach would be, to simply define the dependency on a `T`-instance as a ctor-parameter, and let Autofac build the instance of your BL-class:

```
public class SomeBusinessLogic // defined in your *BL* project
{
  public SomeBusinessLogic(SomeDependency someDependency)
  {
  }
}

var someBusinessLogic = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<SomeBusinessLogic>(); // in your *FRONTEND* project
```